# Java Charset InputStreamReader, File Channel Differences

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm trying to read a (Japanese) file that is encoded as a UTF-16 file.

When I read it using an InputStreamReader with a charset of 'UTF-16" the file is read correctly:

```
try {
        InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("JapanTest.txt"), "UTF-16");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
        String str;
        while((str=in.readLine())!=null){           
            System.out.println(str);
    }
    in.close();
}catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

However, when I use File Channels and read from a byte array the Strings aren't always converted correctly:

```
    File f = new File("JapanTest.txt");
    fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    channel = fis.getChannel();
     MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map( FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0L, channel.size());
     buffer.position(0);
    int get = Math.min(buffer.remaining(), 1024);
    byte[] barray = new byte[1024];
    buffer.get(barray, 0, get);
    CharSet charSet = Charset.forName("UTF-16");
    //endOfLinePos is a calculated value and defines the number of bytes to read
    rowString = new String(barray, 0, endOfLinePos, charSet);               
    System.out.println(rowString);
```

The problem I've found is that I can only read characters correctly if the MappedByteBuffer is at position 0. If I increment the position of the MappedByteBuffer and then read a number of bytes into a byte array, which is then converted to a string using the charset UTF-16, then the bytes are not converted correctly. I haven't faced this issue if a file is encoded in UTF-8, so is this only an issue with UTF-16?

More Details:
I need to be able to read any line from the file channel, so to do this I build a list of line ending byte positions and then use those positions to be able to get the bytes for any given line and then convert them to a string.

Comment: probably `endOfLinePos` is calculated wrong; if it's an odd number, it's trouble since UTF-16 requires even number of bytes.

Comment: I suspect that possibly the 1024 character groups are splitting a UTF-16 character in "the middle."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code unit of UTF-16 is 2 bytes, not a byte like UTF-8. The pattern and single byte code unit length makes UTF-8 self-synchronizing; it can read correctly at any point and if it's a continuation byte, it can either backtrack or lose only a single character.

With UTF-16 you must always work with pairs of bytes, you cannot start reading at an odd byte or stop reading at an odd byte. You also **must** know the endianess, and use either UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE when not reading at the start of the file, because there will be no BOM.

You can also encode the file as UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, the `InputStreamReader` does some transformations the normal `new String(...)` does not. As a work-around (and to verify this assumption) you could try to wrap the data read from the channel like `new InputStreamReader( new ByteArrayInputStream( barray ) )`.

Edit: Forget that :) - [Channels.newReader()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newReader%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20java.lang.String%29) would be the way to go.

Comment: I need to be able to read any line from the file channel, so to do this I build a list of line ending byte positions and then use those positions to be able to get the bytes for any given line and then convert them to a string.

Comment: For line-wise processing the [`LineNumberReader`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) is used.

Comment: True - but I want to use File Channels because the files can be large so it will save a lot of memory.

Comment: So, why not use `new LineNumberReader( channel.newReader(...) )`? - It will read the file sequentially, buffering only a small amount of data (kilobytes maybe) at any instant.